# NTP Server and Client millisecond precision sync

Tags: linux, networking, time, synchronization, ntp

I'm facing an issue with getting my NTP Client (Running on Ubuntu) to have it's time sync to a NTP Server (running on windows) to millisecond precision.

The NTP Server runs using an open source python module: https://github.com/limifly/ntpserver

The NTP Client has `server 192.168.0.28 prefer iburst` in the ntp.conf file.

I found that the client requests for the time every 2 - 15 seconds.

To check the time I have a simple python script running on both devices and I'll do a screen shot with both print outs displaying:

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            print datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%f")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Exiting..."
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting deviations of 5 seconds to 100 milliseconds.

When I run the command:

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpdate -s [NTP SERVER ADDRESS]
sudo service ntp start
```

I found that I can get 70 milliseconds to 5 microseconds precision immediately. After about 5 minutes I can see that the time deviates by 7 seconds...

My goal is to get millisecond precision so my question is am I doing everything correctly to achieve this goal? Also is there a better way to measure the time sync time?

Comment: What about PTP (precision time protocol) See: https://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/lcjp14_ichikawa_0.pdf

Comment: @Deepaklal Correct me if I'm wrong but from my understanding you need special hardware to use PTP?

Comment: @Sam Can you clarify; are you running ntpd if so can you please edit your question with the output from ntpq -pcrv Note you should of had ntp running for a while before you issue the command & post the result. Also worth nothing that ntpdate id depreciated and shouldn't really be used any more. If your trying to get high precision you could run your own stratum 0 server with a GPS (Or similar receiver)

Comment: Assuming that the network between the two machines is a local one without any components introducing worse that sub-sub.millisecond delays, you might also check with the creators of the python script whether their server might suffer from varying processing delays (e.g. internal maintenance). For high precision sync I would avoid interpreted languages and prefer servers using compiled code. Why did you opt against standard ntpd implementation?

Comment: You should also verify the internal clocks of your two servers. Some systems are using clocks that suffer from being throttled due to power saving activity.

Comment: And you might check temperature gradation of both systems as some quarzes might significantly change frequency even on small changes of temperature.